# Unable to assign a value to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Unable to set a value to a specific cell:

```
   Dim employee As String
   employee = "EMPLOYEE"
   MsgBox employee & recordcountdb + 1 & ColNumDBCategory2

   Cells(recordcountdb + 1, ColNumDBCategory2).Value = employee
   Cells(recordcountdb + 1, ColNumDBCategory3).Value = "BIRTHDAY"
```

Have been able to do that for other cells in same row where the variable holds a value read from another file. However the above 2 commands are basically just setting predefined values to cells. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain whats going wrong e.g. do you get an error message? Also, post the code you've used so we can make suggestions on it.

Comment: Hi I am getting an Run Time error 1004 on the below code , Application defined or object defined error.If you look at the above code I am displaying allvariables involved and they are correctly displaying. So its strange i get an error here while i can do the same for other cell values. The only diff between other cell values is that they are being read and stored in a variable from another file while this variable is being declared when trying to assign.

Comment: What is `recordcountdb` and `ColNumDBCategory3`? Please update you question to explain this (and perhaps add additional code to meet the standards of [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It will be an issue with 'recordcountdb', 'ColNumDBCategory2', 'or ColNumDBCategory3' not holding a number that can be used as a row or column i.e. <1 or > 16k / 1m

Comment: Hello this has been resolved. The ColNumDBCategory3 was declared as a string so even though was displaying the value was not processing it.